# Mockito test for spring method fails due to wrong result in the response

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I am using mockito to test a method that returns a String. When I run the test, it fails with an error that says

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Response content expected:<true> but was:<false>
```

I am new to Mockito, I can't figure out what the problem is. Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The method I am testing:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/menus/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String submitEditMenu(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("menu") Menu menu) {

    return String.valueOf( iMenuService.updateMenu(menu));

}
```

The Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring-security.xml")
public class TestMenuController{
    @Mock
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Mock
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    @Mock
    private IMenuService iMenuService;
    @Mock
    private WebApplicationContext weApp;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private MenuController menuController;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(menuController).build();
    }
    @Test
    public void testSubmitEditMenu() throws Exception {
        Menu menu = new Menu.MenuBuilder()
                    .setMenuId(1)
                    .setMenuName("menu1")
                    .build();

        when(iMenuService.updateMenu(menu)).thenReturn(true);

        MvcResult result = 
             mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/menus/update")
            .param("menuId", "1")
            .param("menuName", "menu1"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content()
            .contentType("text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string("true"))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andReturn();

        assertNotNull(result);
}
```

}

The response

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1], Content-Length=[5]}
     Content type = text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
             Body = false
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Comment: so, basically: your code doesn't do what you expect it to do? the chance that the problem is the test, is minimal. it's either your code, your configuration, or your expactation that is wrong. Have you debugged to check whether your code behaves as you expect it to?

Comment: False is the default return value for a mock of a function that returns a Boolean, so are you sure `menu` is getting matched? What happens if you use `any()`? How is `Menu` implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Menu` object you use while mocking and the `Menu` object created after request are different.

You can use `when(iMenuService.updateMenu(Mockito.any(Menu.class))).thenReturn(true);` for mocking to make it working.

However, this makes free the results of test from properties of `Menu` object. You can use this instead;

```
when(iMenuService.updateMenu(Mockito.any(Menu.class))).then(invocationOnMock -> {
       Menu menu = invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(0, Menu.class);
       return menu.getMenuId() == 1 && "menu1".equals(menu.getMenuName());
    });
```

Now the mock object will return true if and only if it gets a `Menu` object with id=`1` and name=`menu1`

Comment: Your solution didn't work, but you are right about the two Menu objects. When I debugged I found that it compares the two Menu objects and returns null because they are not the same.